# INSERT IF EXIST UPDATE the table using PHP and Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am writing a PHP Code and having problem with conditions of a query. Also if you could tell my how could i accomplish this by using Stored Procedure in Mysql that would be so nice.
 My task is to run INSERT query if User foreign key don't exist. If User foreign ke is present in the "User_ID" column then update it.
But here i can put condition of unique on Column 'User_ID' in database. So no duplicate event will occur from Database.
The following query is showing this error
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN 23 NOT IN (SELECT User_ID FROM VoiceMail) ELSE UPDATE VoiceMail SET Urg' at line 3**

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from Users",$con);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $info=getVM($row['Ext'],$ast);
    $info[3]=$row['User_ID']; // To insert User_ID from Users table
    $query="INSERT INTO VoiceMail (Urgent, New, Old, User_ID)
            VALUES ($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3])
            WHEN $info[3] NOT IN (SELECT User_ID FROM VoiceMail)
            ELSE UPDATE VoiceMail SET Urgent=$info[0], New=$info[1], Old=$info[2] WHERE User_ID=$info[3]";
    if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else echo "Database Updated..!";
```

Comment: Are you after [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: Mysql does not support, `INSERT .. ELSE UPDATE...`. You can simply just do `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Yes..! but here i can put condition on of unique on Column 'User_ID' in database. So no duplicate event will occur from Database

Answer (score 0):

Is User_Id an unique key? If so, you can use `ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO VoiceMail (Urgent, New, Old, User_ID)
VALUES ($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3])
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Urgent=values(Urgent), New=values(New), Old=values(Old)
```

Comment: but here i can put condition on of unique on Column 'User_ID' in database. So no duplicate event will occur from Database

Answer (score 0):

Just simply query like :

```
$query="REPLACE INTO VoiceMail (Urgent, New, Old, User_ID)
        VALUES ($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3])";
```

It will replace values if already exist, insert new if does not exist.

Hopefully it will help